# Accessing WebApplication exposed by EC2 instance in Private Subnet

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

We have a web-application page exposed at port 9090 on an EC2 instance that lives in the private subnet of our AWS setup. 
We have a bastion host that is in the public subnet, and it can talk to the instance in the private subnet. We can also ssh to the instance thru the ssh tunnel of the bastion.

Is there a guide to setting up a proxy on this bastion host to access the webpage in the browser that is served on the http://PrivateSubnetEC2Isntance:9090/, by redirecting the traffic to/from http://PublicBastion:9090/?

I tried setting up a HAProxy (on bastion), but it doesn't seem to work: there are no errors in the HAproxy logs, but accessing the page  http://PublicBastion:9090 just times-out.

Comment: Most of the cases the issue relies with security group configuration. so double check on it whether the port 9090 is allowed to be accessed from Bastion host. Hope the EC2 instance in private server is reachable from the Bastion host? (For this enable ICMP traffic in Security Group attach to the EC2 instance and do a ping)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though this is not an answer, most likely it could be due to:

1. Security group rules: Did you open port `9090` for everyone in Bastion security group?
2. Is your HAProxy listening on `0.0.0.0` and not on `127.0.0.1`?

Comment: Thanks! It was the HAProxy configuration that needed changing.

Comment: Actually, I realized that there is still an issue. Earlier I had only tested the setup with opening port 80 on bastion and the internal EC2 and running apache on it. Now when I change HAProxy config to: <code> .  listen 
  HTTPTraffic 0.0.0.0:80 . 
        timeout connect 10s . 
        timeout client 1m . 
        timeout server 1m . 
        mode tcp . 
        server vpcNode 172.31.4.222:9090 .  The request from outside world gets connected, but then hangs in Accept mode. Any suggestions?

Comment: Nevermind, figured it out: earlier I was redirecting traffic of bastion:80 to ec2:80 for apache and it worked, but bastion:80 to ec2:9090 was not working. So, configured HAProxy to listen on 9090 on the bastion host, and opened 9090 on bastion, closed 80. And not it works.